# How to trigger more than one View Element in one method (React Native JS)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

There are two WheelPickers in our View. When we want to change the picker elements, other pickers are also affected.

How can i fix that problem.
(I don't want to write two different Picker Select method.
how do I know which picker is called in a method.)

**Selected item method**:

```js
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    selectedItem : 19,
    selectedItem2 : 19,
    itemList: numberList
  };
}
    onPickerSelect (index) {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: index,
        })
    }
    onPickerSelect2 (index) {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem2: index,
        })
    }
```

**Picker View:**

```js
                <Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
                    itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
                    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect(index)}>  
                        {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
                            <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
                        ))}
                </Picker>
```

**Second Picker:**

```js
                <Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
                    itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
                    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect2(index)}>  
                        {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
                            <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
                        ))}
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One solution** is to add a second paramter to onPickerSelect containing the name och the state property.

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    selectedItem : 19,
    selectedItem2 : 19,
    itemList: numberList
  };
}

onPickerSelect(index, selectedItem) {
        this.setState({
            [selectedItem]: index,
        })
} 

<Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
    itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect(index, 'selectedItem2')}>  
           {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
                 <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
    ))}
</Picker>
```

**Another**, probably better, solution is to break out the picker with functions to an own component which you include twice in your current file/component.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This solutions is working on my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper around `Picker` component and pass the common values as props. This will also lead to better code re-usability.

*PickerWithID.js*   (wrapper component for `Picker`)

```
class PickerWithID extends Component {
    render() {
        const {id , pickerValues, onPickerSelect, itemList } = this.props
        return (
            <Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
            selectedValue={pickerValues[id]}
            itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
            onValueChange={(index) => onPickerSelect(index, id)}>  
              {itemList.map((value, i) => (
                <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
              ))}
            </Picker>

        )
    }
}
```

You can then use your new wrapper component as:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [19,19], // multiple picker values stored as array
      itemList: numberList
    };
  }

onPickerSelect (index, pickerID) {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;
    selectedItems[pickerID] = index;
    this.setState({
        selectedItem
    })
  }
```

First Picker:

```
<PickerWithID 
    id={0}
    pickerValues={this.state.selectedItems}
    itemList={this.state.itemList}
    onPickerSelect={this.onPickerSelect}
/>
```

Second Picker:

```
<PickerWithID 
      id={1}
      pickerValues={this.state.selectedItems}
      itemList={this.state.itemList}
      onPickerSelect={this.onPickerSelect}
/>
```

**Note**: We can also use loop to render multiple `PickerWithID` component as we need to change `id` only.